# Lighting datatable Custom Inline Edit

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I have a custom LWC Page which is used as Public site.

In my Page I have form which will populate the data in `Contact` object and display the value in Data table.

I have integrated inline edit in my data table by Using `updateRecord`, I'm getting Invalid Privileges.

So i was trying to  update the field value by calling Apex Controller.

```
 <lightning-datatable key={stu.Id} key-field="Id" data={stu.spitems} columns={studentProgram}
                                data-record-id={studentsData.studentId} draft-values={draftValues}
                                hide-checkbox-column="true" 
                                onsave={handleInlineEdit} show-row-number-column=false>
                            </lightning-datatable>
```

```
handleInlineEdit(event) {
    var draftValuesStr = JSON.stringify(event.detail.draftValues);
    alert(draftValuesStr);
}
```

I'm editing the two row's value in the data table, On click save calling the `handleInlineEdit` method, `draftValuesStr` have JSON value like Below

```
[
{
    "StartDate": "2020-05-10",
    "Id": "a022w0000033ckoTFC"
},
{
    "StartDate": "2020-05-03",
    "Id": "a022w0000033ckpFDC"
}
]
```

I can pass this `draftValuesStr` to APEX controller, my question here is - How we can update the value in each row by Id in APEX. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean how to deserialize `draftValueStr` for updating existing Contacts, then it would be better to create wrapper class and use `JSON.deserialize()` method:

```
public class ContactWrapper {
    public String StartDate;
    public String Id;
}

String draftValueStr = '[{"StartDate": "2020-05-10","Id": "a022w0000033ckoTFC"},{"StartDate": "2020-05-03","Id": "a022w0000033ckpFDC"}]';

List<ContactWrapper> drafts = (List<ContactWrapper>) JSON.deserialize(draftValueStr, List<ContactWrapper>.class);
```

Then iterate the list to get ids, select contacts and update them:

```
Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>();
for (ContactWrapper draft : drafts) {
    ids.add((Id) draft.Id);
}
Map<Id, Contact> contacts = new Map<Id, Contact>([SELECT StartDate FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :ids]);

for (ContactWrapper draft : drafts) {
    if (contacts.get(draft.Id) != null) {

        // there we need some date formatting
        // to get Date from draft.StartDate
        Date draftDate = someFunctionToFormatDate(draft.StartDate);

        contact.get(draft.Id).StartDate = draftDate;
    }
}
update contacts.values();
```